# How can I make a 2d array that has pairs of random elements of another array?

Tags: java, arrays, random, 2d

I'm trying to make 2d array that has paired random elements. For example, {{1,1,3,4},{3,1,4,1}}. For my project, I'm going to use strings instead of numbers since I'm going to create a game of matching pairs. This is my attempt.

```
private String[] test = { "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet", "white" };
private final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 4;
private String[][] board = new String[DEFAULT_SIZE][DEFAULT_SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {

                board[i][j] = test[rand.nextInt(7)];

            }
        }
```

This gives me an array filled with random elements of array `test`. I don't know what to do next
I tried doing this also but I still don't get pairs for the elements of the array.

```
private String[] temp = new String[DEFAULT_SIZE * 2];
temp[0] = board[0][0];
        temp[1] = board[0][1];
        temp[2] = board[0][2];
        temp[3] = board[0][3];
        temp[4] = board[1][0];
        temp[5] = board[1][1];
        temp[6] = board[1][2];
        temp[7] = board[1][3];
        for (int i = 2; i < DEFAULT_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DEFAULT_SIZE; j++) {
board[i][j] = temp[rand.nextInt(7)];
            }
        }
```

It's random, sometimes I get 3 of the same elements of the array which is not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have pairs which means I can have even number of same random element. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

May you are looking for something like this?

```
import java.util.Random;

class RandomPairGenerator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = { "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet", "white" };
    RandomPairGenerator pairGenerator = new RandomPairGenerator();

    String[][] pairs = pairGenerator.randomPairs(test, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < pairs[0].length; i++) {
      System.out.println(pairs[0][i] + " " + pairs[1][i]);
    }
  }

  String[][] randomPairs(String[] collection, int numberOfPairs) {
    Random random = new Random();
    String[][] pairs = new String[ 2 ][ numberOfPairs ];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPairs; i++) {
      pairs[0][i] = collection[ random.nextInt(numberOfPairs) ];
      pairs[1][i] = collection[ random.nextInt(numberOfPairs) ];
    }

    return pairs;
  }
};
```

To generate your 2D array assign values using random indexes in your source vector.